# Can't get query results to work as a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the following to try to display the data in the 'calls' field where the "people_id" field equals 1:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT calls FROM ae8vo_survey WHERE people_id = '1'");

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query1);

echo $result['calls'];
```

Nothing shows up even though the query works fine.

Comment: Use `print_r($result);` to show what data it has.

Comment: first, did you try running mysql_error() after to see if there was an error? second, is there a reason you're using the old mysql methods instead of pdo or, at least, mysqli?

Comment: @RN Kushwaha `print_r($result);` is the only thing so far that displays something. If I use that and change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` I get the following; `Array ( [calls] => 3 )`. Is there a way to only pull the 3?

Comment: `var_dump($result['calls']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$calls = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT calls FROM ae8vo_survey WHERE people_id = '1'"), 0);

echo $calls;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, you have to call it by number

So try...

```
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) populates both numeric and string indexes by default. So this shouldn't make a difference.